# format names from a list of objects into a string

Tags: python, object, format

I'm trying to insert the names from a list of objects into a string, but I have a hard time comprehending list comprehension before I can come up with a way to add a spacer between them.

```
"need {}".format(i.name for i in lst))
```

what's the right way to do it?

Comment: Can you please post sample input and expected output?

Comment: I guess, you need `'need ' + ''.join(i.name for i in lst)`.

Comment: `"need {}".format(', '.join(i.name for i in lst))`  ?

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks, that's exactly what I was missing. now the question is: how can I mark this post as solved? I guess I need your comment as an answer

Comment: @KiaAzad I turned it into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.join` to add the space between the list's elements, then use `.format`:

```
"need {}".format(', '.join(i.name for i in lst))
```